How to move an existing VM into the care of vm-bhyve?
Some time ago I manually created a VM inside my FreeBSD desktop.
It is using a 32G ZFS volume I created just for it:
% zfs list | grep vm
mypool/i386vm    34.3G  4.85T  18.2G  -

I'd like to use/manage it using the vm front-end provided by the sysutils/vm-bhyve-port. How would I do that?
I set vm_dir to zfs:mypool.
I then "created" the vm-definition using vm create little. I'm now trying to modify its configuration using vm config little:
loader="bhyveload"
cpu=1
memory=256M
network0_type="virtio-net"
network0_switch="pub"
disk0_type="virtio-blk"
disk0_name="i386vm"
uuid="5339d118-....-fc4dd43d225b"
network0_mac="58:....:f2"

However, when I attempt to start the VM with vm start little, I see, that it attempts to invoke bhyveload with a wrong diskpath:
bhyveload -c /dev/nmdm-little.1A -m 256M -e smbios.system.uuid=5339d118-b8e4-11ef-9352-fc4dd43d225b -e autoboot_delay=3 -e bhyve_vm_name=little -d /mypool/little/i386vm little
How would I make it use my existing ZFS volume? If the volume needs to be renamed/moved (withing the same pool) how would I do that?
